# Length of smooth path [Zorich's book]

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I was reading Zorich's book volume I, chapter 6.4 "Some application of Integration" and he proved the following proposition in order to compute the length of smooth curves.

> **Proposition 1.** Suppose the additive function $I(\alpha,\beta)$ defined for points $\alpha,\beta$ of a closed interval $[a,b]$ is such
> that there exists a function $f\in \mathcal{R}[a,b]$ connected with
> $I$ as follows: the relation
> $$\inf_{[\alpha,\beta]}f(x)(\beta-\alpha)\leq I(\alpha,\beta)\leq
>  \sup_{[\alpha,\beta]} f(x)(\beta-\alpha)$$ holds for any closed
> interval $[\alpha,\beta]$ such that $a\leq \alpha\leq \beta\leq b$.
> Then $$I(a,b)=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx.$$
>
> Let us return to the original problem, which we can now state as the
> problem of defining the length of a smooth path $\Gamma:[a,b]\to
> > \mathbb{R}^3.$ Our initial ideas about the length $l[a,b]$ of the path
> traversed during the time interval $\alpha\leq t\leq \beta$ are as
> follows: First, if $\alpha<\beta<\gamma,$ then
> $$l[\alpha,\gamma]=l[\alpha,\beta]+l[\beta,\gamma],$$ and second, if
> $\mathbf{v}(t)=(\dot{x}(t),\dot{y}(t),\dot{z}(t))$ is the velocity of
> the point at time $t$, then
> $$\inf_{[\alpha,\beta]}|\mathbf{v}(t)|(\beta-\alpha)\leq l[a,b]\leq
>  \sup_{[\alpha,\beta]}|\mathbf{v}(t)|(\beta-\alpha). \qquad \qquad \qquad (6.51)$$
>
> Thus, if the functions $x(t), y(t),$ and $z(t)$ are continuously
> differentiable on $[a,b]$, by Proposition 1 we arrive in a
> deterministic manner at the formula
> $$l[a,b]=\int_{a}^{b}|\mathbf{v}(t)|dt=\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{\dot{x}^2(t)+\dot{y}^2(t)+\dot{z}^2(t)}dt, \qquad \qquad \qquad (6.52)$$
> which we now take as the definition of the length of a smooth path
> $\Gamma: [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}^3$.

I'm a little confused how did they obtain $(6.51)$? Looks like a magic.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I think what they are doing here is not a rigorous argument, but rather it motivates the definition of the length of a smooth curve. They are saying that in a time $(\beta - \alpha)$, the curve shouldn't be longer than it's maximum speed times the duration of time, and should be longer than it's minimum speed times the duration of time.